# Need Ontology of software engineering terms

Tags: java, ontology

I'm trying to implement a ***Question Answering System*** based on software engineering ontology.  This is a [class/university?] project; it will use the java language.

Can you please help me locate ***software engineering ontologies*** i.e. ontologies [or even taxonomies / folksonomies ?] that include words and concepts found in the domain of Software Engineering.

**Editor's note**: I took the liberty of rewriting this question. It was initially poorly worded and being misunderstood was closed.  Maybe it can be reopen, for it is programming related and of interest to some SO contributors.

**According to [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091236/hi-all-i-am-doing-my-project-in-question-answering-system-based-on-software-engi):** the poster is looking for an OWL resource: quote, "I need **software engineering ontology.owl** file."

Comment: You really need to provide a much more specific question to indicate what information you're looking for or what problem you're encountering.

Comment: `ontology` doesn't mean what you think it does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology

Comment: Dudes, just because you don't understand some terminology doesn't mean it's not a question.   Please reopen, this is a valid question in the field of information science/AI.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29

Comment: It depends on your attitude to *java*. A diehard opponent might think the OP meant 'oncology'

Comment: @ergosys : right on! In fairness to the folks who closed this question (including myself :-( ), the original posting definitively required a "second read" to make much of any sense.  Realizing my mistake, I edited question and of course voted for its re-opening.

Comment: @v.rekha Never use the words "as soon as possible" in a question here, this is not a company and nobody's getting paid to do your work. Having said that, voting to reopen revised question.

Comment: Good work mjv and ergosys for making something of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try contacting [Dr. Pornpit Wongthongtham](http://www.debii.curtin.edu.au/~ponny/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=24&Itemid=40).  From what I can tell, she worked on a SE Ontology and has published recent papers on it.  At some point the ontology was online at http://www.seontology.org, but unfortunately that domain name is no longer registered.

**EDIT 2** - the domain and website are back online!!